# Select particular text from a varying lenght of text value field

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with following rows in it

```
"XX - Make a determination from receipt of request within 15 calendar days"
"Make a determination from receipt of request or necessary info within 2 business days"
"YYYYYYY - Make a determination from receipt of request within 72 calendar hours"
"ZZZZZZZZZZZ - Make a determination from receipt of request within 30 calendar days"
```

and all types of different combinations with a similar pattern of

```
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"  from    "text I want to get" within ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

The length of X and Z changes and so does the text between from and within but the from and within always exists in the text. How do I make a query to get the text I want to get into a table variable so that I compare it against other columns in the same table and see if they match or not?

I have the table variable and scalar variable in place to get the values. I just need the proper select statement.

Comment: Maybe you should split this data up *before* you store it...

Comment: It looks like the X and Z are also not required. Perhaps you're obscuring the actual content too much which results in a ... bad smelling question

Comment: That data is already stored in the "rule_description" column since its creation.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't fix it once instead of writing an expensive query that splits it up *every time*.

Comment: I dont think my Supervisor is going to be too happy if I pitch this idea to him....Pleaseeee let me know if you have a solution for this query...

Comment: @billinkc.... The XXX, YY and ZZZ represent an altogether different string and they are of varying lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really ugly. Fix the table and stop storing different data points inside a string you need to parse like this *every time*. If your supervisor doesn't understand why this is bad, ask him if he likes to re-program his remote control every time he turns the TV on.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @t TABLE(c VARCHAR(8000));

INSERT @t VALUES
('XX - Make...ion from receipt of request within 15 calendar days'),
('Make a de...ion from receipt of request or necessary info within 2 business days'),
('YYYYYYY - Make...ion from receipt of request within 72 calendar hours'),
('ZZZZZZZZZZZ - Make...ion from receipt of request within 30 calendar days');

SELECT SUBSTRING(c, 1, CHARINDEX('within', c)-1) FROM
(SELECT c = SUBSTRING(c, CHARINDEX('from', c) + 5, 8000) FROM @t) AS x;
```

Results:

```
receipt of request 
receipt of request or necessary info 
receipt of request 
receipt of request
```

Comment: +1 for still providing a solution.